# speed up conditional breakpoints (vs with IIS)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I am debugging an IIS site and I have one conditional breakpoint. There is a loop of about 1000 iterations and the condition of the breakpoint is quite cheap on the cpu (string comparison). It is taking really long (minutes) to complete the debug, is there some kind of way to speed this up?

And would this be faster if I debugged on the development server or IIS express?

Comment: By debug do you mean stepping through each iteration? In general when running code in debug it performs slower than without debug, and obviously much faster in production environment. Try running the code and timing the execution using a Stopwatch Class from System.Diagnostics namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using conditional breakpoints can drastically reduce performance.

I did some test on code that took +- 500 ms to execute. With a conditional breakpoint it took **minutes** to complete.

The solution to this is to use manually invoke the debugger.

```
if (variable == value) { System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); }
```

There is no performance penalty by using this approach, the only slowdown will be the comparison between the variable and the value.